# how can I use a Saas var with three color values like $green: 60, 187, 180 so later background-color: rgba($green, 0.8)?

Tags: css

I am trying to use a Saas var called `$green`:

```
$green: 60, 187, 180;   // 60, 187, 180 are my values in rgb
```

Later I am trying use this color to include in `background-color` propery:

```
.icon-button[aria-label="thumbs up"] {
  background-color: rgba($green, 0.8);
}

.icon-button[aria-label="thumbs up"]:hover {
 background-color: rgba($green, 1);
}
```

I am getting "SassError: $color: 60, 187, 180 is not a color." who can I fix it?

thanks..

Comment: use CSS variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50704217/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DART SASS you can use the `color` build-in module.

[Sass: sass:color](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color)

You could use the `scale` function:

```
color.scale($green, $alpha: -20%)
```

But note that in this example the opacity is reduced by 20% (1 - 0.2 = 0.8). So you can reduce/increase the opacity by this value (not set it to the desired value).

So  a solution would be:

This **SASS**

```
$green: rgb(60, 187, 180); // 60, 187, 180 are my values in rgb

.icon-button[aria-label="thumbs up"] {
    background-color: color.scale($green, $alpha: -20%);
}

.icon-button[aria-label="thumbs up"]:hover {
    background-color: color.scale($green, $alpha: 0%);
}
```

becomes this **CSS**:

```
.icon-button[aria-label="thumbs up"] {
  background-color: rgba(60, 187, 180, 0.8);
}

.icon-button[aria-label="thumbs up"]:hover {
  background-color: #3cbbb4;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Another approach would be to use CSS variables. So, dynamic transparency values ​​must be inserted into the RGB color values ​​using SASS functions and / or mixins and then reassembled into a RGBA string.
I followed this approach to allow the user to add their own themes to a system without having to use SASS themselves.
In this code snipped from me you can perhaps guess what it might look like later. [CSS: CSS Variable is not defined in pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906568/css-css-variable-is-not-defined-in-pseudo-element)